# Deserialize IEnumerable of base classes to derived ones using JavascriptSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have a data class to be serialized, which contains an *IEnumerable* property of derived classes, but storing them as the base class of them:

```
public class ToSerializeClass
{
    public IEnumerable<BaseClass> DerivedClasses{ get; set; }

    public ToSerializeClass ()
        : base(ClassTypeEnum.TestClassType)
    {
    }
}
```

If it helps: the *ClassTypeEnum* enum is for different purposes, but it can identify the type of the derived class later, if necessary, since it gets serialized (for example, if I could use a Dictionary of the enum and Type to solve my problem).

The **serialization completes successfully**, and the serialized classes are all the expected - derived - classes. So, the JSON string is OK.

The problem is, when I try to deserialize the instance of the *ToSerializeClass* class, I have to provide a Type for the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
// sorry for the long names, trying to make it obvious
var deserialized = _serializer.Deserialize<BaseClass>(jsonStringOfIEnumerableBaseClasses);
```

Since I've provided the *BaseClass* as Type, the result of the deserialization is a collection of base classes, and all of the derived information are lost.

How can I deserialize the *ToSerializeClass* instance **to have a list (IEnumerable) of derived classes**?

I have full control over the source code, so I'm able to modify my data classes, to use different collection(s) if necessary, but I'd like to solve it using JavaScriptSerializer if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SimpleTypeResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.simpletyperesolver.aspx) to embed type information into the serialized JSON.

For example:

```
void Main()
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());

    var original = new Container()
    {
        List = new List<A> { new A(), new B(), new C() }
    };

    var json = serializer.Serialize(original);
    var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<Container>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.List[0].GetType() == typeof(A)); // true
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.List[1].GetType() == typeof(B)); // true
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.List[2].GetType() == typeof(C)); // true
}

public class Container
{
    public IList<A> List
    { get; set; }
}
public class A
{ }
public class B : A
{ }
public class C : A
{ }
```

Note that the JSON gets augmented with `__type` members which contain the full qualified name of the type. So the JSON becomes somewhat ugly, for example in my case (running it through LINQPad):

```
{
  "__type": "UserQuery+Container, query_cxbxwu, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "List": [
    { "__type": "UserQuery+A, query_cxbxwu, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" },
    { "__type": "UserQuery+B, query_cxbxwu, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" },
    { "__type": "UserQuery+C, query_cxbxwu, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" }
  ]
}
```

---

Of course, you could also roll your own [JavaScriptTypeResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascripttyperesolver.aspx) which makes this maybe a bit more pretty.

For example a very simple (but also not very good) implementation could just use the direct class names:

```
public class MyTypeResolver : JavaScriptTypeResolver
{
    public override Type ResolveType(string id)
    {
        return typeof(MyTypeResolver).Assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == id);
    }

    public override string ResolveTypeId(Type type)
    {
        return type.Name;
    }
}
```

The resulting JSON would then be a lot simpler:

```
{
  "__type": "Container",
  "List": [
    { "__type": "A" },
    { "__type": "B" },
    { "__type": "C" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected, and the result is still readable, so a big thanks for the JavaScriptTypeResolver wrapper as well! :)